# How to remove code suggestion / help popup in sublime 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I keep getting this annoying code help popup in sublime 3.

It seems to have only appeared recently. I'm not sure if it's part of sublime or some plugin.

Is there a way to disable this from showing?

EDIT:

Turns out this is to do with the package [Naomi](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Naomi). Does anybody know if this is a configurable setting with this package?

[image]

Comment: You can disable a package or remove it completely. `Package Control: Disable a package` and choose from the list _Naomi_ or `Package Control: Remove package` and choose _Naomi_.

Comment: The package https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Naomi has a lot of functionality that I like so once I figured out the package was the issue, I want to know if the package is configurable to remove the pop ups

Answer (score 1):

you need to do following steps:

1. Go sublime Menu bar
2. select preferences
3. add this following code to user file and save it.

Blockquote

```
{
       // Controls auto pairing of quotes, brackets etc
       "auto_match_enabled": false,
       // Enable visualization of the matching tag in HTML and XML
       "match_tags": false,
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it Didn't seem to fix this issue. I added the settings to my user preference JSON file, restarted sublime but still getting the popups. The settings you provided look like they are for sublime default configuration. As per my edit a few days ago, I was able to narrow down the issue to a feature of Naomi (package) which I want to disable. Not sure if it is possible to disable certain features in packages though..

Answer (score 0):

I installed sublime, and disable completions popup by adding

```
"auto_complete": false
```

to the preferences.

You get to the preferences by: Menu Preferences -> Settings. There, you are supposed to edit the User Preferences file by adding custom prefs like the above snippet between the existing curly braces.